# Running tensorflow summarisation service with docker instance

Tags: docker, tensorflow, textsum

Can the tensorflow summarisation [model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/textsum) be invoked using the tensorflow docker instance?

The documentation for the model refers to using `bazel build` as part of the steps for building the model. But running the tensorflow docker container does not allow to run the summarisation model unless the container is build from source, as this model is on master.